# subquery not returning results

Tags: query

this query has 2 subquery (related lists) for teacher and students. teacher_set is the parent and teacher and students are its child object. this is the code:

```
for (teacher_Set__c tset : [Select Id,name, 
                (Select id, name, first_name__c, room_assignment__c, teacher_set__c from teachers__r WHERE id= :myTea),
                    (Select Id, name, first_name__c, parent__c, teacher_set__c from students__r WHERE id = : selectedSId) 
                        from teacher_set__c ]){}
```

however, it only returns the `Id` and `name` of `teacher set`.
what might be the error please help. thank you

Comment: Why are you saying that nothing comes back? How you looking at the results?

Comment: may be you are looking for only `tset`.. You need to check `tset.teachers__r ` and `tset.students__r`  both are list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest run below code in your developer console..

And check the result. If you want to access child records,

Use like this

- `tset.teachers__r` and
- `tset.students__r`

Both are list since One parent Can have multiple childs..

```
     for (teacher_Set__c tset : [Select Id,name, 
                                     (Select id, name, first_name__c, room_assignment__c, teacher_set__c 
                                      from teachers__r),
                                     (Select Id, name, first_name__c, parent__c, teacher_set__c 
                                       from students__r) 
                            from teacher_set__c ])
    {
       system.debug('----'+tset);   
        system.debug('--teachers__r--'+tset.teachers__r); 
        system.debug('--students__r--'+tset.students__r);  
    }
```

Comment: thanks @ratan i have found the items in debug logs. how can i add those in the wrapper if they have different lists?

Answer (score 1):

When you are iterating through `Teacher_Set__c`, the object `tset` contains all the information you queried for:

- `tset.Id`
- `tset.Name`
- `tset.Teachers__r`
- `tset.Students__r`